Tief fliegen or tieffliegen?
There is the composite verb

tieffliegen
-- Duden & Leo

for flying at low altitude. However, one could alternative simply write

tief fliegen

which does sound identical and reads at least as comprehensible as the "special purpose" word. Is there any authoritative/stylistic guidance on to whether a) this particular or b) similar "adverbial composite verbs" (sorry for the clumsy wording) are to be used rather than their "modular" counterparts?
I would be happy with a "case ruling", but would be even happier for a general rule. For researching this question, I came across the term "separable verb", but am unsure whether this word falls under that ruling.

There is no general rule for separable verbs and sometimes both variants (together and separated) exist, but with slightly different meanings.

tief fliegen

is simply an action with an adverb as a qualifier: we fly near ground (verbatim: "deeply", but that would be unidiomatic in English). In the same way we could use "hoch fliegen" (fly high), "gerade fliegen" (fly straight) and so on. On the other hand:

tieffliegen

is considered an activity on its own: "tief fliegen" is the action of flying, which just right now happens on low altitude, "tieffliegen" is flying low as a modus operandi. This is even used when the word is used figuratively: a typical insult would be "geistiger Tiefflieger". This is someone intellectually flying low, but not just on a specific occasion but because he can't do any differently - someone who is able to fail even the lowest possible expectations.
There are similar verbs where the same principle applies, arguably the most outstanding one is:

viel versprechend
vielversprechend

The first means "promising much" in the meaning of "making many promises". The second one means "very promising". When it comes to politicians, for instance, you probably want one of the  "vielversprechende", not one of the "viel versprechende" variety.
Here is another example:

schwarz malen
schwarzmalen

The first means simply "to paint [in] black", the second one means "to doomsay" - figuratively for painting the future in the bleakest (darkest) colour possible.

To me, "tief fliegen" doesn't sound idiomatic either. I'd go for "niedrig fliegen" instead.

@Arno niedrig fliegen sounds completely wrong to me.
